# Is there a way to pull third party search indices into the IBM Connections search index?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

[Seedlist SPI](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Seedlist_SPI_ic40a&content=pdcontent) allows you to push IBM Connections search out into third party indices.

Conversely, is there a documented way to pull third party search indices into the IBM Connections search index?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a solution. All you can do is to extend the search box in Connections with your own provider in which case a new page (your page) comes up with your search results only.

Comment: Shame. That would be really nice. I believe that the search is based on Lucene, so likely could be adapted. Maybe I'll try probing it with [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/).